# How to embed visual studio Code in flutter web/mobile app

Tags: android, visual-studio-code

I am creating a flutter web/mobile app and I want to integrate vscode or similar so that the user could write code from the app. Is that possible? If it's impossible with vscode, is there any other powerful code editor that can do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [browser version](https://vscode.dev/)  vs code? It already runs on a browser.

Use [Webview plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) or like this

```
new MaterialApp(
  routes: {
    "/": (_) => new WebviewScaffold(
      url: "https://vscode.dev/",
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("Vscode webview"),
      ),
    ),
  },
);
```

Comment: Yes but i want to embed it in my own app

Comment: Check the edited answer now.

Comment: The thing is, I want it to work like leetcode and similar websites. The user should be able to write code and I should be able to get the output. Not sure that it's possible with WebView